# WebDriver getting an element java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm accessing a website with webdriver, and I want to change an element in it.

I want to know how to access an element and change it. In this case I want to add text to an element i.e. transform this:

```
<span data-id="tag-dist-Lisboa" title="Para eliminar uma das opções, faça duplo clique.">
</span>
```

Into this:

```
<span data-id="tag-dist-Lisboa" title="Para eliminar uma das opções, faça duplo clique.">
    Some random text
</span>
```

My main problem has been finding the element.

I have added above some of the [HTML](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxo5hF15vtsLQXV6N011YlBxZFU), if you need more information please say so.

Comment: you need to provide the surrounding html, its not possible to identify the element with what you have provided.

Comment: html code Provided

Comment: Made the question a little easier for others to readily understand what you're stuck on. Please also consider adding the specific error you're getting (if any) as this will help others identify the issue.

Comment: I get that but I'm trying to do what I wrote, I've consulted several websites on the subject and tried multiple ways and none seems to work. I could post  everything I tried here but it won't be any easier to understand, just more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

As I have already posted one answer on your previous question-

Use following code to set value for the `span` tag-

```
int textLength = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@data-id='tag-dist-Lisboa']")).getText().length();

if(textLength<=0)
{

     WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@data-id='tag-dist-Lisboa']"));
     JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
     js.executeScript("arguments[0].innerText = 'Your Text Here'", element);
}
```

Explanation :-

Find your required `span` tag with `data-id` attribute and check if it contains text or not If yes then use that text value as per your choice.

If not then set **your required text** for that `span` tag

Let us know is it as per your question or some other you want to do ?

Comment: It returns an error `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate a node using //span[@data-id='tag-dist-Lisboa']`



In the web site if I copy xpath at the element it cpoies `//*[@id="searchform"]/div[2]/div/form/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/span`   but even with that it returns the same error.

Comment: Can you add some more `html` which you having above and below the span tag